# Soundcloud API .getSounds only returns the first 5 objects

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I am using the [HTML5 Widget Api](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget) to take a SoundCloud playlist with 14 songs and store the information about every song in an array. 
I use the `.getSounds` method as following:

```
  function loadTracks(){
    myPlayer.player.getSounds(function(ret){
      myPlayer.playlistInfo = ret;
    });
  }
```

It correctly returns an array with 14 spots. The first 5 spots contain exactly what i want, but the last 9 have different information that does not seem to be related to the song.

[this is how the returned array looks like](http://niklas-may.de/soundCloud_return.png)

I could recreate the problem with different playlists. I only get the correct information for the first 5 songs.

Does anyone has and idea on how to solve this? [I set up a codepen for this](https://codepen.io/klasma/pen/NyqBba?editors=0011)
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was struggling with the same problem. For me it looks like `SC.Widget.Events.READY` is sometimes firing before the Widget is really completely ready.

A safe solution would be to loop through a function and check the array for its completeness until all the data you need is there. In my example on [Code Pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vdaMWe) I check the array every 200 ms for all titles and break out of the loop on success.

Comment: Oh, and you should set the height of the iframe large enough to display all the tracks at once. That was another issue causing the problem I experienced when trying to access a playlist with around 30 tracks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the data is all valid - resource type: sound, type: track - but it looks like the API is not returning the full set of information for each song in the playlist beyond the fifth. It's only returning the artwork URL and extended information for the first 5, but I believe the rest of the songs are still accessible by their id. If you need the extra Information, you may have to query the SoundCloud API for each specific song beyond the fifth index (if length > 5), which will probably return the full info for each song. You'll have to do many queries with this method, however

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, there is no method to get the song info for a specific ID within the [widget api](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget). Currently, you can not register your app for full API access.

Answer (score 1):

The real answer... **It is not possible**. `getSounds` wont return all the track info for a playlist at once like you expect it to. The reasons:

- The Widget API is an half-baked, insufficient, poorly-documented, abandoned API.
- The full SoundCloud API has more functionality, but has been closed off for many many years, and will likely never return.
- SoundCloud has no real developer support at all anymore.
- SoundCloud as a whole company seems to have been circling the drain financially for several years (I recall several years ago they almost shut down before getting a new CEO or something). I speculate that this is causing the above shortcomings.

---

But I didn't create a new answer just to say that.

I need a media player for a redesign of my website. The SoundCloud widget is so ugly and incomplete and inflexible, but SoundCloud as a service already provides streaming audio and recording of song plays/downloads/comments, which would be a big effort to reimplement. Also for some reason, SoundCloud is the standard for embedding sharable audio on websites (look at any sample library demo page). Bandcamp has a widget too, but it can only do widgets by albums and not playlists, and also doesn't show things like play numbers or supporters, and is also completely un-customizable. So I really wanted to find a way to make this dumb Widget API work.

Here is a *REALLY HACKY AND UGLY* way I think I found that *hopefully* works consistently. *Use with caution*.

It literally just goes through each track with `.next()` as fast as it can, calling `getCurrentSound` repeatedly on each until it loads and returns the full song info.

```js
// once you know how many tracks are in the widget from a getSounds call...

const fullTracks = [];

// do the following process same amount of times as number of tracks
for (let track = 0; track < tracks.length; track++) {

  // make periodic attempts (up to a limit) to get the full info
  for (let tries = 0; tries < 100; tries++) {
    // promisify getCurrentSound (doesn't handle error)
    const sound = await new Promise((resolve) => player.getCurrentSound(resolve));

    // check if full info has loaded for current sound yet
    if (sound.artwork_url) {
      // record full info
      fullTracks.push(sound);
      // stop re-trying
      break;
    } else 
      // wait a bit before re-trying
      await new Promise((resolve) => window.setTimeout(resolve, 10));
  }

  // move to next track
  player.next();
}

// go back to first track again
player.skip(0);
```

On my machine and internet connection, for 13 tracks, this takes about **300ms**. It also throws a bunch of horrible errors in the console that you can't `try`/`catch` to suppress.

Comment: You could also have it fallback to the normal widget if the process fails. P.s., I hate this very much 

Comment: [Here is the repo for my website and specific SC replacement component](https://github.com/vincerubinetti/vincentrubinetti.com/blob/main/src/components/ThePlayer.vue), and [here is the same thing on Software Heritage archive of the same thing in case I change the repo](https://archive.softwareheritage.org/browse/origin/directory/?origin_url=https://github.com/vincerubinetti/vincentrubinetti.com&timestamp=2023-07-02T06:28:32Z).

Comment: One note: I've recently found that on mobile I have to make sure the invisible original SC iframe is actually in the viewport (e.g. `position: fixed; top: 0;`) or it won't trigger the SC onReady event.